# Shopify Blocks CollectionList

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I am trying to access and loop through the collection list inside the blocks:

The following code should loop through this collection list

```
<!-- If The Category Has So Many Subs -->
<div class="sub-cat-childs-container">
{% for block in section.blocks %}
{% case block.type %}
{% when 'Sub-Category' %}
{% if shop.locale == 'en' %}<style>.subCategory::after{float: right}</style>{% endif %}
  <div class="sub--category--contnet" id="sub-category-{{ block.settings.sub_category_collection.id }}">
  <div class="sub-sub---items-row">
    Loop Throug The CollectionList {{ block.settings.sub-subcategory-collection_list }}
  </div>
 </div>
{% endcase %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The following is the schema I am trying to get the collection list from it:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name" : "Main Category",
    "settings" : 
    [
      
    ],
    "blocks" : 
    [
      {
        "name" : "Sub-Category",
        "type" : "Sub-Category",
        "settings" :
        [
          {
            "type": "collection_list",
            "id": "sub-subcategory-collection_list",
            "label": "Sub Sub-Categories"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "presets" : 
    [
      {
        "name" : "Main Category"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Any one can help me to display all the collection in this collecion List
id:sub-subcategory-collection_list.

Thank you all...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `for` loop to loop over the collections you have selected, for example:

```
{% for collection in block.settings.sub-subcategory-collection_list %}
    {{ collection.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

The `collection_list` type gives you an array of Collection objects which you can loop over, as documented [here](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#collection_list)

As a side note, you should aim to keep all your setting IDs as [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), to match Shopify's practice guides